# How to import a file and how to call it where need it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to import a file with only variables where I am requiring only svgs,

```
// THESE ARE THE SVGS I NEED 
import doubleSvg from '../DecisionOverlay/img/button-double.svg';
import hitSvg from '../DecisionOverlay/img/button-hit.svg';
import splitSvg from '../DecisionOverlay/img/button-split.svg';
import standSvg from '../DecisionOverlay/img/button-stand.svg';

const standSymbolSvg = document.getElementById('stand-symbolSvg');
const hitSymbolSvg = document.getElementById('hit-symbolSvg');
const doubleSymbolSvg = document.getElementById('double-symbolSvg');
const splitSymbolSvg = document.getElementById('split-symbolSvg');

const standSymbolSnap = snap(standSymbolSvg);
const hitSymbolSnap = snap(hitSymbolSvg);
const doubleSymbolSnap = snap(doubleSymbolSvg);
const splitSymbolSnap = snap(splitSymbolSvg);

const standSymbolSvgContent = Snap.parse(standSvg.content);
const hitSymbolSvgContent = Snap.parse(hitSvg.content);
const doubleSymbolSvgContent = Snap.parse(doubleSvg.content);
const splitSymbolSvgContent = Snap.parse(splitSvg.content);

standSymbolSnap.append(standSymbolSvgContent);
hitSymbolSnap.append(hitSymbolSvgContent);
doubleSymbolSnap.append(doubleSymbolSvgContent);
splitSymbolSnap.append(splitSymbolSvgContent);
```

so, I need a module that I can import so I won't repeat my code, because I am repeating this exact same code in 4 different files, so I need to know how to import it and how to call it where I need it

Comment: So, put this in a module and import it where needed. Not sure what the issue is. You already seem to know how to import a module.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of this in a file that `exports` each variable, and then `import *` to get it all

Lib module
    import doubleSvg from '../DecisionOverlay/img/button-double.svg';
    import hitSvg from '../DecisionOverlay/img/button-hit.svg';
    import splitSvg from '../DecisionOverlay/img/button-split.svg';
    import standSvg from '../DecisionOverlay/img/button-stand.svg';

```
export const standSymbolSvg = document.getElementById('stand-symbolSvg');
export const hitSymbolSvg = document.getElementById('hit-symbolSvg');
export const doubleSymbolSvg = document.getElementById('double-symbolSvg');
export const splitSymbolSvg = document.getElementById('split-symbolSvg');

const standSymbolSnap = snap(standSymbolSvg);
const hitSymbolSnap = snap(hitSymbolSvg);
const doubleSymbolSnap = snap(doubleSymbolSvg);
const splitSymbolSnap = snap(splitSymbolSvg);

export const standSymbolSvgContent = Snap.parse(standSvg.content);
export const hitSymbolSvgContent = Snap.parse(hitSvg.content);
export const doubleSymbolSvgContent = Snap.parse(doubleSvg.content);
export const splitSymbolSvgContent = Snap.parse(splitSvg.content);

standSymbolSnap.append(standSymbolSvgContent);
hitSymbolSnap.append(hitSymbolSvgContent);
standSymbolSnap.append(doubleSymbolSvgContent);
splitSymbolSnap.append(splitSymbolSvgContent);

export standSymbolSnap;
export hitSymbolSnap;
export splitSymbolSnap;
```

Some other module

```
import * as lib from 'lib';
//lib.standSymbolSnap is accessible
```